# How can I find a record that equals a value inside a JSON array

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I have the following Table mytable

```
id   |      Json        
1    | {"test":[], "partList":[{"partid": 44, "partNum": "1234"}, {"partid": 34, "partNum": "2423"}]}
2    | {"test":[], "partList":[{"partid": 23, "partNum": "8343"}, {"partid": 34, "partNum": "2423"}]}
```

I'm trying to query `where id = 2 and partNum = 2423`

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
select *
from mytable
where id = 2
and '2423' IN (select value from OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(Json, '$.partList'), '$.part'))
```

What would be the most efficient way to query?

Comment: "What would be the most efficient way ..." -- Not to (a)buse JSON in the first place but relational means like a linking table...

Comment: I agree, but i did not have any other options or a say in db design.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

```
select *
from mytable
CROSS apply OPENJSON(Json, '$.partList') WITH ( partnumber nvarchar(100) '$.partNum' )
where partnumber = '2423'
and id = 2
```